# How to remove event listeners correctly in this function

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

```
public function doAddItem(itemConcepto:int):void{
                modalCfd = new modalCFDItems();
                modalCfd.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, closeHandler);
                modalCfd.addEventListener("addItemResult", addItem_resultHandler);
                modalCfd.addEventListener("addItemResize", addItemResize_resultHandler);                
                PopUpManager.addPopUp(modalCfd, this, true)
                PopUpManager.centerPopUp(modalCfd);
            }
            private function addItem_resultHandler(event:Event):void{   
                addItemStuff();
                PopUpManager.removePopUp(modalCfd);
                removeListeners("modalCfd");
            }
            private function closeHandler(event:CloseEvent):void{
                PopUpManager.removePopUp(modalCfd);
                removeListeners("modalCfd");
            }
            public function removeListeners(listener:String):void{
                if(listener == "modalCfd"){
                    modalCfd.removeEventListener("addItemResult", addItem_resultHandler);
                    modalCfd.removeEventListener("addItemResize", addItemResize_resultHandler);
                    modalCfd.removeEventListener(Event.CLOSE , closeHandler);
                }
            }
```

As you can see I'm a newbie with good practices (in pretty much anything) How can I remove the event listeners correctly? That's a Pop Up I'm handling there. Sorry if that function doesn't make much sense, I simplified it to fit stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a reference to your object so just use that in your removelisteners function.

```
public function doAddItem(itemConcepto:int):void{
                modalCfd = new modalCFDItems();
                modalCfd.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, closeHandler);
                modalCfd.addEventListener("addItemResult", addItem_resultHandler);
                modalCfd.addEventListener("addItemResize", addItemResize_resultHandler);                
                PopUpManager.addPopUp(modalCfd, this, true)
                PopUpManager.centerPopUp(modalCfd);
            }
            private function addItem_resultHandler(event:Event):void{   
                addItemStuff();
                PopUpManager.removePopUp(modalCfd);
                removeListeners();
            }
            private function closeHandler(event:CloseEvent):void{
                PopUpManager.removePopUp(modalCfd);
                removeListeners();
            }
            public function removeListeners():void{
                modalCfd.removeEventListener("addItemResult", addItem_resultHandler);
                modalCfd.removeEventListener("addItemResize", addItemResize_resultHandler);
                modalCfd.removeEventListener(Event.CLOSE , closeHandler);
            }
```

Comment: Oh sorry, that condition I added because I have multiple pop up instances on my module, I wanted to create one function to remove all of them. But even if I removed the condition, the function doesn't work correctly.

Comment: You know, I got it right, I believe the popup behaved freaksih because I positioned it wrong under other condition that I would not care to post here. since it might confuse more. Thanks.